# what do positive real parts of eigenvalues mean?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, eigenvalues, stability, hyperbolic-pde, advection

I am solving a 1D advection problem of the the form $$d{Q}/dt = [A]{Q}$$ where {Q} is the vector of unknowns and [A] is the matrix of coefficients of spatial discretisation. I have worked out the eigenvalues of [A] to get an idea about the stability of the semi-discretised system and I am getting eigenvalues with positive real parts plus imaginary parts. I know positive real parts are a sign of instability, but my results show the smooth travelling of a wave. I wanted to know what conclusions I can draw from this? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can only conclude that either your analysis or your code (or both) is incorrect.

Comment: The correct word is "instability", not "insatiability" (even though the latter would be an interesting choice as well).

Comment: @David, how about when the eigenvalues are zero? Are there any good references for this?

Comment: You mean $A$ is diagonalizable and all eigenvalues are zero?  Then $A$ is the zero matrix and the problem is trivial.

If you want to ask another question, either edit your question or start a new one.  Comments are not questions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what if the real parts are zero?  (the question is pretty similar, can I change the heading of this one? )

Comment: @ David, I have posted it as a new question now ...